# Render JSON from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

How can I convert `JSON` from `PHP/Laravel` and convert it to JSON Javascript. I already have the JSON string from PHP, the only problem is it only renders as a string. I want it to be a json in javascript. Please see my code below.

```
$('#email').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    valueField: 'email',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['email', 'name'],
    options: [JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('{!! $users !!}'))]
});
```

Example output of `$users`:

> {"name":"John Doe","email":"john@doe.com"},{"name":"Frank Franky","email":"frank@frank.com"}

I want it to be like this in JS (for the options property above):

```
[{"name":"John Doe","email":"john@doe.com"},{"name":"Frank Franky","email":"frank@frank.com"}]
```

More reference:

https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: JSON is JSON, there's no difference between javascript and php.

Comment: That **is** JSON. Wrapping it with `[]` just means it's now an array of JSON...

Comment: The example output of `$users` will not `stringify` properly because it's not valid, it's a comma separated list of objects whereas it seems like it should be an array. Only the first object will be stringified, returning: `{"name":"John Doe","email":"john@doe.com"}` and ignoring the rest.

Comment: Can you show me how are you getting $users? Because to get JSON in `{!! $users !!}` you have to `{!! json_encode($users) !!}`

Comment: @dacastro4 laravel already handles this conversion for you when you convert a collection to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $users is a Laravel collection, it doesn't make sense to try to print it and call JSON.stringify on it.  It's a PHP object, you'd need to perform the string conversion at the PHP level.

However, Laravel automatically converts collections it to a JSON string for you when you print it out.  Just use JSON.parse.

```
options: [JSON.parse('{!! $users !!}')]
```

For  Laravel collections:

```
(string) $users === $users->toJson() === json_encode($users)
```

Comment: You're right! Just used `json_encode` since I customize the data using array. Then use `options: [JSON.parse('{!! $users !!}')]`.

Comment: Keep in mind, JSON.parse isn't converting it to JSON, it's converting it to an javascript object or array.

Comment: Oh, now I know. Thanks for the tip. I thought it is JSON.